# Como pegar o próximo atributo de uma array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Boa noite galera, então, to travado num código aqui. Eu tenho uma array de objetos, e irei receber um nome de entrada, que se encontra em um dos objetos "display" do array abaixo, por exemplo "Márcio Magalhães".

Após isso, eu preciso procurar o display e o nome do objeto seguinte a esse, por exemplo nesse caso seria "Alex Jones" e "F1207158".

```
const list_members = {
  "members": [{
    "value": "646d70b7f6974459b188174aa8a564fe",
    "type": "User",
    "display": "Márcio Magalhẽs",
    "name": "B133232",
    "$ref": "examplefortest.com"
  }, 
  {
    "value": "646d70b7f6974459b188174aa8a564fe",
    "type": "User",
    "display": "Alex Jones",
    "name": "F1207158",
    "$ref": "examplefortest.com"
  }, 
  {
    "value": "646d70b7f6974459b188174aa8a564fe",
    "type": "User",
    "display": "Bibiana Fonseca",
    "name": "G123454",
    "$ref": "examplefortest.com"
  }]
}
```

Minha dúvida é como pegar esses dados, tentei começar implementar algo assim mas não consegui progredir

```
const { members: [display, name]} = lista_membros.find(({members})) => members.includes("Márcio Magalhães"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar o [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/findIndex) para procurar no array o índice desse nome/display que tens. Depois é só acrescentar `+1` e tens o índice do próximo.

Atenção que quando chegares ao fim dessa array (quando não houver próximo) a função vai retornar `undefined`.

```js
const list_members = {
  "members": [{
      "value": "646d70b7f6974459b188174aa8a564fe",
      "type": "User",
      "display": "Márcio Magalhẽs",
      "name": "B133232",
      "$ref": "examplefortest.com"
    },
    {
      "value": "646d70b7f6974459b188174aa8a564fe",
      "type": "User",
      "display": "Alex Jones",
      "name": "F1207158",
      "$ref": "examplefortest.com"
    },
    {
      "value": "646d70b7f6974459b188174aa8a564fe",
      "type": "User",
      "display": "Bibiana Fonseca",
      "name": "G123454",
      "$ref": "examplefortest.com"
    }
  ]
};

function getUserAfter(display, arr) {
  const startIndex = arr.findIndex(obj => obj.display === display);
  return arr[startIndex + 1];
}

console.log(getUserAfter("Márcio Magalhẽs", list_members.members));
```